# Vector space is cyclic if and only if it has finitely many invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help me prove that a vector space $V$ is cyclic due to the endomorphism $f$ if and only if it has finitely many $f$-invariant subspaces.

What I've tried:

I've tried the not direct prof, to show that it has infninitely invariant subspaces, then it's cyclic will be inifnite, but it's not going anywhere...

Comment: I've tried use the definition and glue something, but I can't grab the point. Still don't know, where is the key point

Comment: It will help you get an answer if you write down how far you got (the beginning of your proof, up until the point where you get stuck).

Comment: You know, I don't know how to start.

Comment: (This will be true iff the field is infinite, btw)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the vector space is not cyclic, so that there are vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $u$ is not in the cyclic subspace generated by $v$ and $v$ is not in the subspace generated by $u$.  What can you say about the cyclic subspaces generated by vectors of the form $\alpha u+\beta v$?